# A question on What Clause

Tags: grammar

You see Martian paintings and you wonder ***what*** the painter was like.

could someone make me understand why writer not use ***how*** in place of ***what***?

Comment: Please visit [ell.se]

Comment: Homework questions are generally OT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What* in the relative clause 'stands for' the complement of *like*—*X* in the sentence below:

> He is like X.  —What is he like?

*X*, the complement of *like*, must be a nominal expression: a noun phrase (or a clause capable of playing the syntactic role of a noun phrase—but I cannot think of a case in which this would occur with *BE like*, though it may with other uses of *like*).

Consequently, an interrogative or relative which stands for *X* must be a *pronoun*—an interrogative which stands for a nominal.

> He is like a poet.  —What is he like?
>   He is like his father. —Who is he like?
>   He is like one of his brothers. —Which is he like?

But *how* is a 'pro-ad-form', not a pronoun: it stands for an adverbial or adjectival expression, either an adverb or adjective phrase or a preposition phrase which plays the syntactic role of an adverb or adjective phrase.

> He acted well. —How did he act?
>   He acted fine. —How did he act?
>   He acted in great haste. —How did he act?